# A database table is not mapped to Entity Framework model

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have several tables in my database.
One is called my_user, other is called user_details.

While all tables have been mapped into EF models, except the user_details table.

The relation between my_user and user_details tables is one to one not many to many.

When I double clicked the .edmx file, I cannot find the user_details model in that diagram.

What I have done:

1. right click on that diagram
2. choose -> Update Model From Database...
3. in the "Add" tab, I found the missing table, user_details!
4. I ticked it , but the "Next" button was still gray out
5. So I clicked "Finish"
6. Waited for awhile and nothing happen....

**Update**

1. I checked the my_user table, it doesn't contain any attributes from
   user_details table
2. What I also tried was, deleted the .edmx file and
   re-add that again. When adding it, I did saw the user_details table
   is recognized and clicked finish button, still it isn't mapped to
   the Models.

Can anyone figure it out? I have been stuck at here for an hour!!

Thank you.

Comment: try saving the diagram, pressing `ctrl ,`, then type `user_details`, if that exists, it might be somewhere in the diagram

Comment: are you sure that the my_user and user_details tables were not merged into a single entity in the model? a 1:1 relationship would imply you don't need them to be separate

Comment: Hi @AndrewCounts I did check that, but no. Please see my update. Also, the separation between those 2 tables is necessary, coz most of time, user will not have an associated user_detail record.

Comment: separation between the tables does not preclude a single complex class in the model.  However, Entity Framework does have a restriction on 0..1 mappings, in that it expects both tables to use the same PK.

Comment: Also, to save yourself some major confusion, try not to refer to the objects in your Model as "tables", they are classes that represent information that may be stored in one or more tables, but they are not tables themselves.

Comment: Look for Errors to the effect of "Multiplicity is not valid in Role...", if you have a 0..1 relationship but the tables use different PK, Entity Framework isn't able to decide which side should be the 1 (primary) and which should be the 0 (dependent)

Comment: Try check the Error List tab, or right click the file edmx and choose `Open With` -> `XML`, then find if there is any `<!--Errors Found During Generation:`

Comment: hi @AndrewCounts  you are absolutely right. I have found the problem, please see my answer.

Comment: hi @YuliamChandra thx mate, I spotted the issue from the Error list as you said :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why EF doesn't map my user_details table to a model class is simply because I forgot to specify a primary key on that table.

Also the PK in user_details table is same as the my_user table.

Thank you all for your help. :)